# Qual a origem da expressão “Comer Bronha”

Tags: etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica

Segundo [dicionario informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/comer+bronha/), ***comer bronha*** significa:

> Marcar bobeira, falhar, ser desatento.

Contexto aplicado habitualmente:

> O fulano comeu bronha, esqueceu de marcar o número 10, no bingo.
>
> Comi bronha, esqueci de adicionar um contexto na pergunta

Andei pesquisando e não encontrei qual a origem da expressão; alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Pode dar um contexto de utilização da expressão?

Comment: Chamam um tipo de pão de bronha.

Comment: @AndréLyra Referes-te a [este doce de massa de pão doce frita recheada de doce de leite mole](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120806111106AAg4XwG)? Hum... e descobri agora que *bronha* também é 'masturbação masculina'.

Comment: @Jacinto a sério? ahahahah

Comment: "Comer bronha" é dito no Brasil? Eu nunca ouvi. Bronha como "masturbação masculina" eu já ouvi.

Comment: Adicionei um contexto utilizado cotidianamente

Comment: Também nunca ouvi "comer bronha".  Bronha por estes lados só ouço como gíria para "masturbação masculina" conforme comentou @eightShirt

Comment: Eu acho que confundi a broa com bronha. Mas achei uma receita de bronha "
> Broinha recheada
Rende 26 porções Ingredientes Massa: 1 tablete de fermento biológico 3 colheres de sopa de açúcar 2 ovos 1 pitada de sal 1 1/4 de xícara de chá de leite morno 2 colheres de sopa de creme vegetal 1 colher … " Confundiram broinha com bronha na TAG [bronha](http://www.trigoesaude.com.br/tag/bronha)

Comment: Deve ser uma versão de "comi bola"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, a expressão correta é *comer beronha*; a [beronha (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/beronha/) é uma mosca varejeira que, por ser muito rápida, coloca ovos nos alimentos assim que as pessoas acabam de os preparar, e se estas não ficarem atentas, acabam comendo os ovos.

Daí a expressão comer beronha, que é a mesma coisa que comer/papar mosca. Alguém deve ter confundido *beronha* com *bronha* e acabou mudando o dito popular.

Comment: E eu que pensava que só os portugueses é que comiam esses *ee* átonos! :)

Comment: Uma confusão que cria uma expressão bem desconfortável, um perceberia ao descobrir o significado de "bronha".